# Connecting JavaScript to MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am developing a website for a cinema. I have been using Axure for designing the website. I created a web page for seat reservation using the same software. The page has a very long js code. Can I connect this page to the database using PHP? For HTML pages, I did something like this (with PHP):

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
mysql_select_db('cinema'); 
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
$pword = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pword');
$query = "INSERT INTO customers (email, password) VALUES ('$email', '$pword')";
mysql_query($query);`
```

Is there a way to do the same thing for a .js file?

Comment: js is client side. PHP is server side. What you can do is call your php file via javascript using AJAX and then connect to your database.

Comment: Yes and theres' heaps of awesome tutorials that explain how to get ajax to interact with php and in turn the database heres one of many http://www.w3resource.com/ajax/working-with-PHP-and-MySQL.php

Comment: Yes, if you use Node.JS

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect JS directly to your database but you can make php code that will do that connection and get the data you need. And you can call that php script from JavaScript code by Ajax call.

PHP can i.e. generate JSON array out of database data so you can easy parse it on JS side.